# How to solve None degree expression with GUROBI python

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I would like to minimalize the cost of motors, where I have equation, which looks like this

`(Motor*price - other_factor*other_price)/(Motor)`

but when i implement this in my code i get the following error:

> pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.gurobi_direct.DegreeError: GurobiDirect does not support expressions of degree None.

Here is a snippet from my code, that I am using:

Edit: I placed the parenthesis in the wrong place, but this is the corrected code:

```
power_ranges = {
    'Motor1': (0.6, 1.1),
    'Motor2': (2.1, 6),
    'Motor3':(1, 1.94),
    'Motor4':(1, 1.94),
}

prices = {
    'Motor1': lambda x: (x * 5000 - np.square(x) * 100)/x,
    'Motor2': lambda y: (y * 5500 - np.square(y) * 100)/y,
    'Motor3': lambda z: (z * 5100 - np.square(z) * 200)/z,
    'Motor4': lambda a: (a * 5200 - np.square(a) * 300)/a,
}

# Create a Pyomo ConcreteModel
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Define decision variables
model.x = pyo.Var(power_ranges.keys(), domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

# Define objective function
model.cost = pyo.Objective(
    expr=sum(prices[motor](model.x[motor]) for motor in power_ranges),
    sense=pyo.minimize
)

# Define lower and upper bounds constraints
model.bounds_constraint = pyo.ConstraintList()
for motor in power_ranges:
    lower_bound, upper_bound = power_ranges[motor]
    model.bounds_constraint.add(lower_bound <= model.x[motor])
    model.bounds_constraint.add(model.x[motor] <= upper_bound)

    # Include the constraint that the lower bound is either the given lower bound or 0
    model.bounds_constraint.add(model.x[motor] >= min(0, lower_bound))

# Define power constraint
model.power_constraint = pyo.Constraint(
    expr=sum(model.x[motor] for motor in power_ranges) ==5
)


# Solve the optimization problem
solver = SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='python')
solver.options['NonConvex'] = 2
results = solver.solve(model)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 p = x * 5000 - x**2 * 100/x
```

you can try

```
 p = x * 5000 - x * 100
```

(note that x >= 0)

Note that your code does not do `(Motor*price - other_factor*other_price)/(Motor)` (missing parentheses).